Equivalence of Wannier Functions and Atomic Orbital Wave Functions in the Tight Binding Approximation
In tight binding approximation, what I've learned is that we can write the wave function of an electron which satisfies Bloch theorem in lattice as
$$
\psi(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{\mathbf{R}_s} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R}_s}w(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)
$$
where $\mathbf{R}_s$ are the lattice vectors. And in many book, the author says "under the approximation that the wave function can be approximated by the atomic orbital wave function $\phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$ near $\mathbf{R}_s$, then the Wannier function $w(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$ can be chosen as $\phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$". I don't quite understand this. If the approximation means that
$$
\psi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)\approx \phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)
$$
then how can I conclude that $w(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)\approx \phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$ for all $\mathbf{R}_s$ (under other proper approximations e.g. $\phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$ are orthogonal etc.)?
For example in Ashcroft/Mermin, they say that near $\mathbf{R}_s$, the atomic Hamiltonian $H_{at}$ should give $H_{at} \psi =E \psi$, where $\psi$ is the total wave function and $E$ is the atomic energy level of lattice atom in $\mathbf{R}_s$. When I correctly understood this, it should mean that $\psi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)\approx \phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$.

Please give examples of references (book title, author, edition, page and equation numbers).

Maybe those books should add (and perhaps they do, you don't give a reference)  that these atomic orbital wave functions $\phi(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{R}_s)$ are sufficiently localized. If they stretch out to the neighboring sites the claim would not in general be true.

@JosBergervoet yes, I write this as the approximation of orthogonality in the question

@TobiasFünke I think this is a quite general method in dealing with tight binding approximation, for example in Ashcroft/Mermin, they say that near $\mathbf{R}s$, the atomic Hamiltonian $H{at}$ should give $H_{at} \psi =E \psi$, where $\psi$ is the total wave function and $E$ is the atomic energy level of lattice atom in $\mathbf{R}_s$

Why is it so hard to give an exact reference?! I can just repeat: book title, author, edition, page and equation numbers.

@TobiasFünke Because the origin book I read is in German by Kopitzki and in Chinese by Huang. Similar things in English book I've found is Ashcroft/Mermin page 178 eq.(10.4).
